# How can I restore a systemd service after editing it using "systemctl edit service"?

Tags: command-line, services, systemd

I used `sudo systemctl edit name.service` to edit a service, now I no longer need these modifications and I wish to restore it to its default setting.

How can I restore it?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're running a version of `systemd` higher than of "229", then you can simply use:

```
systemctl revert name.service
```

[From github commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/344ca7556bf6c1c8727c19a0eb8751a27dc0a85f):

> This allows dropping all user configuration and reverting back to the vendor default of a unit file.
>
> - It basically undoes what:
>
>   - "systemctl edit"
>   - "systemctl set-property" and
>   - "systemctl mask" do.

Ubuntu 16.04 uses "systemd version 229", so you should remove override file manually:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/name.service.d
```

Then reload systemd daemon and restart your service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart name.service
```

Remember that if you used `--full` with `edit` subcommand to copy the original unit instead of creating a drop-in file, then you should remove `/etc/systemd/system/name.service` instead of the directory.

Comment: a new commit was added to revert units edited with --full too, see : https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/15829/commits/eff1a466b9c7bf55dd2f7d23a703f488ca1d9ace