# How to run fstrim -a regularly automatically?

Tags: ssd, automation, trim

I noticed that manual seldom invocations of `fstrim -av` take a lot of time (over 10 minutes) and report a lot of free space to the SSD:

```
# /usr/bin/time -p fstrim -av
/boot/efi: 503,2 MiB (527671296 Bytes) auf /dev/sda1 getrimmt
/: 377 GiB (404832960512 Bytes) auf /dev/sda2 getrimmt
real 691.65
user 0.00
sys 4.90
```

This makes me think that for whatever reason, the free blocks are not reported by the operating system automatically despite of the `discard` flags in `/etc/fstab`.  So, I wish to go sure and get `fstrim -a` executed regularly; I'm ok with each computer start, each day, each week, or once a month.  What's the best way to arrange this schedule automatically; in other words, into which script file do I add this call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your system by default is setup to do this using systemd. Check the status of the timer:

```
systemctl status fstrim.timer
```

By default, it is set to run `fstrim -A` once every week, as you can see in the output of:

```
systemctl cat fstrim.service
```

There is no use to do this more than once a week, expect for extreme usage with lots of file deletes, moves, etc., where more frequent trimming may be needed.

This actually answers also your question: you can have any job setup to run automatically using `systemd`. You still can use the "old" approach using `crontab`, which still is available by default on Ubuntu.

If you know what you do, you can [edit the service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926690/how-can-i-restore-a-systemd-service-after-editing-it-using-systemctl-edit-servi).

Comment: Running more than once a week can be helpful when the underlying filesystem is stored on a block device shared by other filesystems (i.e. virtual hard disks on a hypervisor with overprovisioned/thinly provisioned storage). fstrim will let you shrink the virtual hard disk device down to the space actually used inside the VM